# Find semordnilap(reverse anagram) of words in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, anagram

I'm trying to take a string input, like a sentence, and find all the words that have their reverse words in the sentence. I have this so far:

```
s = "Although he was stressed when he saw his desserts burnt, he managed to stop the pots from getting ruined"

def semordnilap(s):
    s = s.lower()
    b = "!@#$,"
    for char in b:
        s = s.replace(char,"")
    s = s.split(' ')

    dict = {}
    index=0
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
        originalfirst = s[index]
        sortedfirst = ''.join(sorted(str(s[index])))
        for j in range(index+1,len(s)):
            next = ''.join(sorted(str(s[j])))
            if sortedfirst == next:
                dict.update({originalfirst:s[j]})
        index+=1

    print (dict)

semordnilap(s)
```

So this works for the most part, but if you run it, you can see that it's also pairing "he" and "he" as an anagram, but it's not what I am looking for. Any suggestions on how to fix it, and also if it's possible to make the run time faster, if I was to input a large text file instead.

Comment: Are you only looking for reversed strings? In that case it would be as easy as creating a list of revere words for each sentence and then doing a lookup.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a very slow process?

Comment: Not necessarily. Standard library is implemented in C, at least in case of CPython. So it would be often faster than pure python code. You can measure it with `timeit.timeit` though. For more advanced use-cases you probably should use `nltk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string into a list of words and then compare lowercase versions of all combinations where one of the pair is reversed. Following example uses `re.findall()` to split the string into a list of words and `itertools.combinations()` to compare them:

```
import itertools
import re

s = "Although he was stressed when he saw his desserts burnt, he managed to stop the pots from getting ruined"

words = re.findall(r'\w+', s)
pairs = [(a, b) for a, b in itertools.combinations(words, 2) if a.lower() == b.lower()[::-1]]

print(pairs)
# OUTPUT
# [('was', 'saw'), ('stressed', 'desserts'), ('stop', 'pots')]
```

EDIT: I still prefer the solution above, but per your comment regarding doing this without importing any packages, see below. However, note that `str.translate()` used this way may have unintended consequences depending on the nature of your text (like stripping `@` from email addresses) - in other words, you may need to deal with punctuation more carefully than this. Also, I would typically `import string` and use `string.punctuation` rather than the literal string of punctuation characters I am passing to `str.translate()`, but avoided that below in keeping with your request to do this without imports.

```
s = "Although he was stressed when he saw his desserts burnt, he managed to stop the pots from getting ruined"

words = s.translate(None, '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~').split()
length = len(words)
pairs = []
for i in range(length - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, length):
        if words[i].lower() == words[j].lower()[::-1]:
            pairs.append((words[i], words[j]))

print(pairs)
# OUTPUT
# [('was', 'saw'), ('stressed', 'desserts'), ('stop', 'pots')]
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! It works, but I was trying to do this in the function without using the libraries for efficiency. Is there a way to do this without using re and itertools?

Comment: @codingenthusiast `itertools.combinations()` is very fast (I haven't checked performance of `re.findall()` so can't say for sure on that one but there is certainly overhead involved in matching regex patterns). It is definitely possible without the libraries but not sure if it would be more performant or not since you would still have to find a way to deal with punctuation, etc - see answer edit.

Comment: Thanks, both of you for explaining this to me. It's good to know that itertools is fast, I'll try both approaches on a large text file and see what the run times are :)